# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Internal error encountered

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-admin

I'm trying to send push notifications via a Firebase Cloud Function, but getting an internal error.

```
Error: Internal error encountered.
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:253:16)
    at Function.FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:283:16)
    at Object.createFirebaseError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-errors.js:34:47)
    at FirebaseMessagingRequestHandler.buildSendResponse (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request.js:119:47)
    at /srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request.js:94:30
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at /srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request.js:93:30
    at <anonymous> errorInfo: [Object], codePrefix: 'messaging'
```

My function is simple enough:

`sendPushNotification.js`

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const messaging = admin.messaging();

module.exports = function(title, deepLink, deviceTokens) {
  var message = {
    notification: {
      title: title
    },
    data: {
      deepLink: deepLink,
    },
    tokens: deviceTokens
  };

  console.log(`Sending notification ${title} with Deep Link ${deepLink} to ${deviceTokens.length} devices`);
  console.log(deviceTokens);

  return messaging.sendMulticast(message).then(response => {
    console.log(`Success: ${response.successCount}, failure: ${response.failureCount}`);

    if (response.failureCount > 0) {
      console.log(response.responses)
    }
  });
}
```

The weird thing is that sometimes it does work, but maybe one in 10? The other times I get this less-than-helpful error. The `APNs Authentication Key` is uploaded in the Firebase Console in the project settings. The App Bundle ID is correct. I'm at a loss for what else could be going on.

(Yes, I am giving the function an array of valid deviceTokens.)

None of the other questions on StackOverflow seem to be related to this internal error, the answers on those questions don't apply here.

Comment: Hm, now I randomly got the error `Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service Raw server`. There must be _something_ wrong _somewhere_ at least.

Comment: After editing the key in the Apple developer site, not changing anything, simply hitting save, that auth error is now gone. Weird.

Comment: And now I am getting the same auth error again, after I didn't get an error and a push notification was delivered.

Comment: Same Error on my side. Any news on your side? Got a fix?

Comment: I ended up recreating the key and uploading it again, and it solved itself, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I recreated keys like @KevinRenskers and (only) that made it working again.

Comment: I used the 'edit' button to view the details of my APNS key, but did not change anything. After that I got this error. Editing the key again and going all the through 'saving' it fixed the issue, even though I could not download the key again.